# Backup Openfire and restore it to another machine

Tags: backup

I am using [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) as collaboration software in Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain.

Today I am planning to install [Elastix](http://www.elastix.org/) 2.3 on my Hyper-V server for VoIP implementation that **Elastix** has built-in openfire server.

Is there any solution to backup the Windows version of Openfire and restore it on Elastix?

Comment: Last time I checked OpenFire used some built-in Java database system. That one could be ported to other systems back then. It was about 304 years ago, however.

Comment: Do you use the openfire embedded db? If it's a large organization it might be worth migrating to a MySQL db for greater flexibility.

Comment: that, you are right, but I'm using embedded DB right now!

Answer (score 0):

Openfire is great software!

Try installing the "User Import Export" plugin from the Plugins tab (under Available Plugins). Then go to your Users/Groups tab and you will notice the new "Import & Export" option. Reverse on the new system and hopefully that will make the migration easier!

BTW: the embedded database is HSQL and uses the connection string:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:/opt/openfire/embedded-db/openfire
```

if you have a little java know-how, you could connect to the same database and write a script to export the data to whatever format you prefer then insert to your MySQL database. The schema should be the same on both databases (I think!).